# Module For Managing Page-Specific Permissions

Tags: users

I am curious if there is a module or a combination thereof that allows one to manage page- or resource-specific permissions? That is, if I wanted to create a Role and lock it to only being able to edit a certain page, how would I go about  achieving that?

Comment: Roles can already be set to editing nodes only they originally created. Could you expand upon this?

Comment: Which part is not clear?

Comment: My ultimate goal is to limit certain users to being able to edit only certain pages or resources.